Lag or first_value doesn't work when year is changed
    with
    --my input--
    x(id1,med_id,dt,dt_tm,casemgr_id,casemgr_clntid,status) as (
    select 123456,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 194567,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 11:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 789101,98410,date'2024-04-24',timestamp'2024-04-24 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 194587,98410,date'2024-04-25',timestamp'2024-04-25 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 234561,98410,date'2024-04-26',timestamp'2024-04-26 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 456789,91956,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 08:00:00',99012,87567,-2
    union all
    select 998415,91956,date'2024-12-20',timestamp'2024-12-20 07:00:00',99012,87567,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-16',timestamp'2023-11-16 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-21',timestamp'2023-11-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-01',timestamp'2023-12-01 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-04',timestamp'2023-12-04 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-02-02',timestamp'2024-02-02 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-05',timestamp'2024-07-05 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-21',timestamp'2024-07-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-21',timestamp'2024-07-23 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    );

Input above. What I am trying to achieve is that for a combination of med_id, casemgr_clntid and dt, the first record sorted by date should be valid, and the subsequent records should be invalid if it falls within 180 days. Then the code should look for the first record after the 180 day timeframe, that record should be valid, and this record should be the starting point and the subsequent rows should be invalid. If greater than 180 days, it should be valid. if there are multiple records on the same day, like in the first two instances, the earlier record should be valid since it's earlier timestamp and the other should be invalid since it's later in the day,  In other words, the first record at 9am should be valid while the second record should be invalid.   I have also put the desired output at the end.
So for example in the last three rows, where the record on 5th july is valid since it's the first record after the 180 day time window, but subsequently it should be invalid (in other words, it has restarted the time window). So the records on 21st July and 23rd july should take the record on 5th july as a starting point
-- sql qry which was suggested, tweaked to explictly put the date format...
SELECT
  id1
, med_id
, dt
,dt_tm
, casemgr_id
, casemgr_clntid
, CASE WHEN (
           to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd)' -
         , lag(to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd')) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid ORDER BY dt_tm)
         )  is null
      OR (
           to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd)' -
         , lag(to_char(dt,'yyyy-mm-dd')) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid ORDER BY dt_tm)

         )  >180
    THEN 'valid'
    ELSE 'invalid'
  END AS status
FROM x
ORDER BY med_id, casemgr_clntid, dt_tm 
;

I also tried subtracting by dt_tm, but the dt_tm-first_value(dt_tm) doesn't work.

Error: invalid operation

    with
        --my desired output--
        x(id1,med_id,dt,dt_tm,casemgr_id,casemgr_clntid,status) as (
        select 123456,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 09:00:00',12345,67891, 'valid'
        union all
        select 194567,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 11:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 789101,98410,date'2024-04-24',timestamp'2024-04-24 09:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 194587,98410,date'2024-04-25',timestamp'2024-04-25 09:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 234561,98410,date'2024-04-26',timestamp'2024-04-26 09:00:00',12345,67891,'invalid'
        union all
        select 456789,91956,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 08:00:00',99012,87567,'valid'
        union all
        select 998415,91956,date'2024-12-20',timestamp'2024-12-20 07:00:00',99012,87567,'valid'
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-16',timestamp'2023-11-16 07:00:00',12434,87438,valid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-21',timestamp'2023-11-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-01',timestamp'2023-12-01 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-04',timestamp'2023-12-04 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-02-02',timestamp'2024-02-02 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-05',timestamp'2024-07-05 07:00:00',12434,87438,valid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-21',timestamp'2024-07-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-23',timestamp'2024-07-23 07:00:00',12434,87438,invalid

        );


@DaleK I added the desired output as well as an explanation of what I am trying to achieve

Not an answer, but FYI the "invalid operation" error is because you need to specify the type of interval for the result, e,g.  dt_tm-first_value(dt_tm) DAY(4)

why are you converting your dates to strings?

@Andrew Initially I just used the queries suggested, but it failed when the year changes from 2023 to 2024. I tried changing the datatypes to yyyy-mm-dd and it doesnt work. The row with 2/2/2024 should be invalid because it's within 6 months, but it shows valid for me. I am using teradatasqlassistant and the date format in my database is mm/dd/yyyy. That's why I tried to change it to yyyy-mm-dd

Can you use recursive queries in  teradata?

If I am not mistaken, the dt column is redundant, as the date is included in dt_tm. And the whole thing is not about the first dt per med_id and casemgr_clntid anyway, but about their first (i.e. minimum) dt_tm.
SELECT
  id1,
  med_id,
  dt,
  dt_tm,
  casemgr_id,
  casemgr_clntid,
  CASE WHEN dt_tm = MIN(dt_tm) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid)
         OR dt_tm >= CAST(MIN(dt_tm) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid) AS DATE)
                     + INTERVAL '181' DAY
    THEN 'valid'
    ELSE 'invalid'
  END AS status
FROM x
ORDER BY med_id, casemgr_clntid, dt_tm;


The code that you suggested doesn't work in the scenario where there is a change of year. I have given examples. When the year changes to 2024, the row with the date 2/2/2024 should be invalid, but the codeshows valid. The code works perfectly in the scenario where the dates are on the same day and the timestamp is sorted

The year doesn't matter at all. It's a date plus 180 days. Here is a fiddle showing that the query works properly (2/2/2024 is invalid as it should be): https://dbfiddle.uk/cz59FEtJ

You are right, 2/2/2024 should be invalid, whereas I am getting valid by running your query. Not sure if it is because I am using teradata sqlassistant? The date formats in my database is mm/dd/yyyy. Is that the reason why?

I get the same results even with using the LAG that was suggested. 2/2/2024 is coming as valid using TDSQLA, whereas as you indicated it should be invalid because it's within the 180 days

Dates have no format. It is the tool you are using that displays the dates in some particular format. Same for timestamps.

So, if you run the exact same query from my fiddle in teradata, you get a different result than PostgreSQL does in my fiddle? That would indicate a bug in teradata. Possible, but not very likely.

Your code works perfectly. I have one scenario which I edited my question. So in addition to your code (which works correctly), it should look for the first row after the initial min(dt_tm) after the 180 days time frame, that row should be valid and the subsequent rows should be invalid because it takes this row as a point of reference. How would you modify your query to achieve it?

So, you want to write a query that looks for the first day, say 2000-01-01. This is valid. All rows in the following 180 days (till about end of June 2000) are invalid. Then you look for the first day entry after that first periods end. Let's say it is 2000-10-01. Then this is valid, the dates in the following 180 days (till about end of March 2001) are invalid, and then again you look for the next day to start the next period? Yes? For this you'd need a completely different query, as this is an iterative process which requires a recursive query in SQL.

Yes, that's correct. I have no idea how to do this. Can you assist?

You shouldn't make such significant changes to your request. Your original request was about looking at the first day and then apply the same formula to each row. Now you want to look at the first day, mark some rows, find another day, mark some rows and so on. This is a completely different task. My answer doesn't match your altered request and future readers with a similar problem will be greatly confused. Roll back your changes and ask the altered question in a separate request. (Or just look up how recursive queries work and figure out the solution yourself.)

I didn't realize it would be a separate query,  I will ask it as a separate question

You need LAG and the check for NULL which marks the first value, that is valid and then you need to check also if 180 day is already past which you check with > 180
    with
    --my input--
    x(id1,med_id,dt,dt_tm,casemgr_id,casemgr_clntid,status) as (
    select 123456,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 194567,98410,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 11:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 789101,98410,date'2024-04-24',timestamp'2024-04-24 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 194587,98410,date'2024-04-25',timestamp'2024-04-25 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 234561,98410,date'2024-04-26',timestamp'2024-04-26 09:00:00',12345,67891,-2
    union all
    select 456789,91956,date'2024-04-19',timestamp'2024-04-19 08:00:00',99012,87567,-2
    union all
    select 998415,91956,date'2024-12-20',timestamp'2024-12-20 07:00:00',99012,87567,-2
          union all
    select 998425,91956,date'2025-05-21',timestamp'2025-05-21 07:00:00',99012,87567,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-16',timestamp'2023-11-16 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-11-21',timestamp'2023-11-21 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-01',timestamp'2023-12-01 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2023-12-04',timestamp'2023-12-04 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-02-02',timestamp'2024-02-02 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
union all
  select 01786,18745,date'2024-07-05',timestamp'2024-07-05 07:00:00',12434,87438,-2
    ),
      CTE as (
SELECT
  id1
, med_id
, dt
,dt_tm
, casemgr_id
, casemgr_clntid
      ,           dt -
          LAG(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid ORDER BY dt_tm) dayspassed

FROM x),
      CTE2 AS(
      SELECT
        id1
, med_id
, dt
,dt_tm
, casemgr_id
, casemgr_clntid
      ,dayspassed
      ,SUM(dayspassed) OVER (PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid ORDER BY dt_tm)/180 n
      FROM CTE)
      SELECT
              id1
, med_id
, dt
,dt_tm
, casemgr_id
      
, casemgr_clntid
      ,dayspassed
      ,CASE WHEN (n IS NULL)
      OR
      (n > CASE WHEN LAG(n) OVER (PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid ORDER BY dt_tm) IS NULL 
      THEN 0 ELSE LAG(n) OVER (PARTITION BY med_id, casemgr_clntid ORDER BY dt_tm) END)
      THEN 'Valid'
      ELSE 'invalid'
      END status
      FROM CTE2
ORDER BY med_id, casemgr_clntid, dt_tm 
;




id1
med_id
dt
dt_tm
casemgr_id
casemgr_clntid
dayspassed
status




1786
18745
2023-11-16
2023-11-16 07:00:00
12434
87438
null
Valid


1786
18745
2023-11-21
2023-11-21 07:00:00
12434
87438
5
invalid


1786
18745
2023-12-01
2023-12-01 07:00:00
12434
87438
10
invalid


1786
18745
2023-12-04
2023-12-04 07:00:00
12434
87438
3
invalid


1786
18745
2024-02-02
2024-02-02 07:00:00
12434
87438
60
invalid


1786
18745
2024-07-05
2024-07-05 07:00:00
12434
87438
154
Valid


456789
91956
2024-04-19
2024-04-19 08:00:00
99012
87567
null
Valid


998415
91956
2024-12-20
2024-12-20 07:00:00
99012
87567
245
Valid


998425
91956
2025-05-21
2025-05-21 07:00:00
99012
87567
152
Valid


123456
98410
2024-04-19
2024-04-19 09:00:00
12345
67891
null
Valid


194567
98410
2024-04-19
2024-04-19 11:00:00
12345
67891
0
invalid


789101
98410
2024-04-24
2024-04-24 09:00:00
12345
67891
5
invalid


194587
98410
2024-04-25
2024-04-25 09:00:00
12345
67891
1
invalid


234561
98410
2024-04-26
2024-04-26 09:00:00
12345
67891
1
invalid




SELECT 14



The code that you suggested doesn't work in the scenario where there is a change of year. I have given examples. When the year changes to 2024, the row with the date 2/2/2024 should be invalid, but the codeshows valid. The code works perfectly in the scenario where the dates are on the same day and the timestamp is sorted

that has nothing to do with the dates, you changed the rules, a perfect sql solution is very difficult to ger another programming language like php python c# will be better suited for this, a solution that is better suited  for you , is abouve but ut would only catch days since the first treatment and will  not take in consideration the other valid dates see example here https://dbfiddle.uk/UlqJza8U  with casemgr_id 99012
